# Designing a validation engine for form fields

Tags: c#, rule-engine

I want to create a form validation engine that I will further customize, but as a base, I need some guidance on how to build the base.

Form fields can be your standard form fields like:

```
textbox
drop down list
checkboxes
etc.
```

So this validation engine will be given a list of types of form fields, and then
a set of rules for each form field.

For example:

Say you have a textbox, the rule will apply to the textbox and it has to make sure the value is "blue", or '123' (so it can be a string or integer value).

**I'm looking for some direction on how I should go about laying out my classes.**

Any design patterns to use?

```
public class Rule
{
   public RuleType  RuleType {get;set;}
   public ComparisonType ComparisonType {get;set;}
}

public enum RuleType
{
    TextBox,
    DropDownList
}

public enum ComparisonType
{
    Equal,
    GreaterThan,
    GreaterThanOrEqual,
    LessThan,
    LessThanOrEqual
}
```

Does this look like a good start?

On the Rule class, how will I set the value the form field has to be.

i.e. Say the comparisonType is 'Equal', I have to say equal to "Blue" or 123.  I can't have a string property because I have to compare for integers or booleans also.

Ideas?

*How would you design this?*

Comment: "How would you design this?" - I would base it on the Data, not the GUI. And probably use DataAnnotations and go home early.

Comment: This is just the base of what I have to do, so I will need to customize it more which probably makes data annotations out of the picture, but reading about it thanks.

Comment: Normally, any complex data validation is done with business rules. Web form validation is not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute based data validation (DataAnnotations) is a powerful model because it's easy to apply validation both to the UI and Business Object layers, and is highly extensible.

You didn't state your environment, but if you're using MVC here's a good starter:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

To learn about creating custom validators:

http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=182

To use DataAnnotations with web forms, have a look at this contributed implementation:

http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html

Comment: Someone contributed an implementation for WebForms. Adding a link to my response.

Comment: The problem with attributes is that you have to recompile and redeploy the project if the rules change (and they do).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using lambdas/anonymous methods, this might make your validations more readable:

[C# Lambda Expressions or Delegates as a Properties or Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142090/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-or-delegates-as-a-properties-or-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Try  [Oval](http://oval.sourceforge.net) , its an object validator and you can apply your constraints as annotations in your class file itself. Basically you can make your form as a pojo class and annotate the fields with Oval validations / constraints.
[1](http://oval.sourceforge.net)